# Angular ng-value not assigning value to "HTML5" Input List element while using Datalist with ng-repeat, would like to set a default value

Tags: cross-domain

(program):1 Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "https://run.plnkr.co" from accessing a frame with origin "https://plnkr.co". Protocols, domains, and ports must match

Answered :
Using Ng-init to call setter function under controller.

Comment: Here is plunk   https://plnkr.co/edit/Ksc9nl0JF8cZxPiHFIAb

Comment: Got Plunk working but now would like to set default value to "Now", the first value in datalist.

Comment: Added HTML Input List with datalist and assigned a value to Input element  : Working Great !

Comment: Answered my question : added a new function under controller to set the value of the Input element and used ng-init to call the new $scope function.

Comment: Cleaned up plunkr